# Is it possible to compile Objective-C code on a PC?

Tags: objective-c, linux, windows

I would like to start learning Objective-C for future iOS development. I understand that there are many large hurdles in getting an iPhone app to work on a PC but I'm trying to avoid all of that and just get familiar with the Objective-C language itself without all of the added mobile features.

Is there a way to compile Objective-C programs on a PC to learn just the language without any extra iOS features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, definitely. Have a look at [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/) - it's a framework that contains the Objective-C runtime library and most of the Foundation classes. You can learn the language very well by using this package with GCC (gobjc) and MinGW on Linux or Windows.

Comment: Thanks @H2CO3. Would you happen to know if it's possible to use an IDE with it? Do any exist?

Comment: Cocotron has gone stale, but may be relevant.

Comment: @EinDoofus On Windows, I'd suggest you use Notepad++. On Linux, I found Gedit, nano and emacs useful.

Comment: I'd free a partition for Ubuntu GNU/Linux or FreeBSD. Avoid GCC and use clang for Objective-C 2.0.